# Variable within a Linux shell expression

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have an `hour` variable in shell that contains UNIX time in seconds.

Then If want to format this hour, I use

```
date -u -d @$hour +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z"
```

which works. However, I want to store the result of the above expression to another variable, so when I do:

```
formatted=$(( date -u -d @$hour +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z" ))
```

it does not work. I do not know how will I reference the `hour` variable within an evaluation expression (whatever it is called).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The expression

```
formatted=$(( date -u -d @$hour +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z" ))
```

use the `$((` which works only for *arithmetic*.  Change the double parentheses to single:

```
formatted=$( date -u -d @$hour +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z" )
```

The latter works for *strings*.

For reference (these are POSIX shell features, not bash-specific):

- [2.6.4 Arithmetic Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) discusses `$((`
- [2.6.3 Command Substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) discusses `$(`

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) is subtly wrong.  The use of double parentheses after `$` introduces a quite distinct context in Bash, which is known as [arithmetic context](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression).

So just drop one pair of parentheses.

```
formatted=$(date -u -d @$hour +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z")
```

The use of backticks is syntactically valid, but [discouraged](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

```
formatted=`date -u -d @$hour +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z"`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as following:

```
hour=1447409296  #Whatever timestamp value you want to set
formatted=`date -u -d @$hour +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z"`
echo $formatted
```

or:

```
formatted=`date -u -d @$hour +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z"`
```